# jQuery AJAX calls error callback on 202 response- shouldn't that be a success callback?

Tags: jquery

Well its all in the title. I'm trying to check the user's password before performing destructive actions:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/path/to/post.json',
  data: { password: '**********' },
  success: function() { console.log("Success!"); },
  error: function() { console.log("Error!"); }
});
```

In console:

```
202 Accepted 123ms
Error!
```

I thought 403 Forbidden for wrong password and 202 Accepted for correct password would be appropriate response codes, but I don't know much about HTTP to be honest.

jQuery version 1.8.3

Comment: The error callback is not fired due to the status of 202 but due to an error in parsing the response as JSON (most likely). Are you responding with valid json? (empty body is invalid json) And invalid password would probably be 401 or 400 for its practicality.

Comment: I think so? the response is just a string. In console it looks like `Invalid Password`. Does it need to be a key/value pair?

Comment: I don't think 202 has anything to do with "correct password." http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Well no, you don't need a key/value pair, a string can be a top level value in JSON. But a string in JSON is `"Invalid Password"`, not `Invalid Password`. What are you using on server-side? You should json encode your responses, not construct json manually which you can see is error-prone.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney haha indeed it does not. Back to 200 for me. Thanks for the link btw

Comment: @Esailija you're 100% right, I'd forgot to convert the string to json, aka string with quotes. Put an answer about invalid json and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error callback is not fired due to the status of 202 but due to an error in parsing the response as JSON. For jQuery, `2xx` and `304` is a success.

If the response body is `Invalid Password` that's invalid json and triggers the jQuery error when it tries to parse it. A proper JSON string has quotes around it, like `"Invalid Password"`. You should JSON encode your responses using a JSON serializer, not construct json manually which you can see is error-prone.

Comment: Another reason is when the request body is empty, then jQuery calls the error callback.

Comment: So what is best practice for replies in this case? A useless String? An Empty list? It feels silly while coding my backend to send some garbage data.

Comment: It seems this can be worked around by setting `dataType: null` or `dataType: 'text'`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it working with

```
statusCode: {
  202: function() { console.log("Success!"); },
  403: function() { console.log("Error!'); }
}
```

Instead of `success` and `error` callbacks. Still a little baffling 202 triggers the error one though.